# Compact spectrum of continuous operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I found the following exercise in Conway's Functional Analysis book: 
Prove that for every compact subset $K$ of the plane there exists a continuous operator in Hilbert space with spectrum $K$.


So far I came up with the idea to define the operator in the basis vectors as $f(e_n)=e_n\cdot a_n$, where $a_n$ are dense in $K$. It is clear that the spectrum contains $K$, however, I am not sure, why the other inclusion holds?

Is my approach not correct? What other approach can I use?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\setminus K,$ then for $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_ne_n$ we have

$$
f(x)-\lambda x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n-\lambda)x_n e_n,
$$
from which we immediately get
$$
\|f(x)-\lambda x\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n-\lambda|^2\cdot |x_n|^2\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \inf_k |a_k-\lambda|^2\cdot|x_n|^2=\inf_k|a_k-\lambda|^2 \cdot\|x\|^2,
$$
now, $\inf_k|a_k-\lambda|>0$ since $K$ is compact. This implies that $f-\lambda$ is bounded from below. Since $f-\lambda$ is obviously surjective, we get that $f-\lambda$ is invertible with bounded inverse and you're done.

Comment: Shouldn't each $|a-\lambda|$ be $|a-\lambda|^2$ ?  (The proof still works just fine.)

Comment: Right you are. :)